# Locação dinâmica em C++

Tags: c, c++11

Boa tarde. Gostaria de saber como alocar uma string dinamicamente em C sem perguntar para o usuário o tamanho da String. Apenas colocando ele para escrever a string.

Comment: Olá Giovanne, no título você está falando de C++, no corpo da sua pergunta você fala de C e a pergunta está marcada com tags de C#, C e C++. Essas são linguagens diferentes com APIs diferentes para leitura de strings da input padrão.

Answer (score 0):

Ai não tem como adivinhar né? Mas o que você pode fazer é alocar de um tamanho que você ache vai ser suficiente e depois que ele digitar a string você realoca ela pro tamanho realmente usado.

```
int main()
{
    char *st = (char*) malloc(5000);
    printf("Informe a sua string");
    scanf("%s", st); //supondo que a string não vai ter espaços;
    st = realloc(strlen(st) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso criando uma função personalizada para ler string e ler dinamicamente:

```
char *ler_string(char *nome)
{
    int i = 0;
    char letra;
    nome = malloc(sizeof(char));
    do
    {
        letra = getchar();
        if(letra != '\n')
        {
            nome[i] = letra;
            i++;
            nome = realloc(nome, sizeof(char) * i+1);
        }
    }while(letra != '\n');
    nome[i] = '\0';
    return nome;
}
```

A função acima ler uma string e vai alocando o tamanho dela a medida que encontra uma caractere que não seja o enter no buffer de entrada. Exemplo de uso na main:

```
char *nome;

printf("Digite seu nome: ");
nome = ler_string(nome);

printf("Seu nome eh: %s \n", nome);

free(nome);

return 0;
```

Comment: Note que você está colocando o caractere terminador '\0' **fora** da área alocada para `nome`. De qualquer maneira, apesar de pouco eficiente pela realocações consecutivas, é uma boa solução para strings de tamanho indefinido.

Comment: Realmente, corrigi o erro do '\0' agora.